# Можно ли сохранить страницу в WP, как шаблон для других страниц?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, wp-plugin

Можно ли сохранить страницу в WP, как шаблон для других страниц?

Answer (score 1):

Можно указать вверху страницы комментарий вида

```
<?php /* Template Name: My Custom Page */ ?>
```

Тогда в редактирование этот шаблон можно будет назначить для страницы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробнее тут https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use